# Contractive sequence are Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking the proof in by textbook and I am hung up on something. I know how the authors are proceeding but not sure how they are getting one part of the formula. The line of the proof is:
$$(C^{m-2} + C^{m-3} + \dots + C^{n-1}) |x_2 - x_1| = C^{n-1}\frac{1-C^{m-n}}{1-C} |x_2-x_1|$$

I realize that the authors are using the geometric progression, but I am not seeing how we get equality. Could someone break this down for me?

Comment: In the future, please use LaTeX and mathjax in your questions. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Whatever $\;\Bbb C\ni c\neq1\;$ is:

$$c^{m-2}+c^{m-3}+\ldots+c^{n-1}=c^{n-1}\left(1+c+\ldots+c^{m-n-1}\right)=$$

$$=c^{n-1}\frac{c^{m-n}-1}{c-1}$$

Comment: Well not whatever... $c \neq 1$

Comment: Good point, @nik. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$
C^{m-2}+C^{m-3}+...+C^{n-1} = C^{n-1}(1 + ... + C^{m-n-2} + C^{m-n-1}) = C^{n-1}
\frac{1-C^{m-n}}{1-C}
$$